# OSX Escalated Privilege

Tags: c++, juce

please, could someone point me into the right direction? Here's the problem, I created my own installer for my synth plugins: VST, VST3 and Component.

On Windows I just set it to ask for Administrator rights and it them can save the plugins anywhere. On OSX the story is different, I couldn't find an EASY way to put files into folders when they don't have the right permissions. Not only that, but I can't open the folder for reading after it is saved, so that's another problem.

Resuming:

A) how to elevate file privileges on OSX so that I can save plugin files (.vst, .vst3, .components) into any folder

B) how can I read data files (such as skin files) from a folder that requires elevated rights?

C) I'm using JUCE, you can check my work at www.Wusik.com

Thank you for any advice.

Cheers, WilliamK

Answer (score 0):

I believe [Authorization Services](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Security/Conceptual/authorization_concepts/02authconcepts/authconcepts.html) is what you would need.

Or you might consider creating an installer package using [Packages](http://s.sudre.free.fr/Software/Packages/about.html).